# What algorithm for predict operator math?

Tags: algorithm, math

For example I have 4 numbers: 10, 3, 2, 1

Then the question is *"How to make 4 numbers above to 24 ?"*

- The answer is (10-2) * (3 * 1) = (8 * 3) = 24

**What is the name of the algorithm in the programming language? to predict the operator (-, +, /, *) in the case above**

Comment: Well, for a start, you could try all permutations and combinations till you get the required number. I feel this is reasonable for 4 numbers but not beyond that.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? This problem can be solved by many different algorithms (or at least algorithmic strategies - brute force, backtracking, branch and bound, and probably even dynamic programming). Are you trying to ask what the name of the _problem_ is?

Comment: I doubt there is a practical problem exactly matching your description, but for a general problem when you can construct something, have a cost function, and constraints is called a [_constrained optimization problem_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_optimization). And the [_branch and bound_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) is one of the relatively simple to code ways to solve optimization problems using smart full enumeration.

Comment: it's not "prediction" there's nothing to predict. You just replace the operators and calculate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a C++ version of the algebra game 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277015/writing-a-c-version-of-the-algebra-game-24)

Answer (score 1):

These fit within the broad class of [constraint satisfaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction) problems - essentially you can easily test a solution, but you need to search to find one. There are several algorithms for dealing with various formulations of constraint satisfaction problems.

Comment: hmm i see.. thanks.. ^_^